# How to Insert Multiple row into database

Tags: php

this is my code .. My problem is when I create multiple row, only the first row only make it into the database .. The next row is not .. For your information, add row function works well... I use the concept of MVC

**View**

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>
    <fieldset>
         <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="amount[]"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="date[]" id="date" /></TD>
            <td align="center" valign="top" nowrap><input name="count1" type="text" id="count1" size="8" maxlength="10" value="10"></td>

    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

**Controller**

```
            $count= $_POST['count1'];

    $amount= $_POST['amount'];
    $date= $_POST['date'];


    for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){

  $this->Model->insertBil($date[$i],$amount[$i]);


 }
```

**Model**
no questions

Comment: what is insertBil method ??? also are you using any framework ?? if than which ??

Comment: in my opinion, the problem lies in the 'controller' not on the model .. This loop is functioning properly?

Comment: what is for $count variable ?

Comment: variable count no function .. I tried to set to 10 .. as well-you can see $ i <= 10;

Comment: you are using it nowhere

Comment: Have you checked with `print_r($date)`?

Comment: the problem is only the first row only make it into the database .. did I miss something?

Comment: @NullPointer : the problem is only the first row only make it into the database.. the next row not..

Comment: you are not using loop to fetch data .... so it will show only first row .loke in mysql we do something `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` we we dont use while loop $row come with only first row